# Making div stick to bottom of another div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a social site and on the posts div at the bottom of the div, I want to have a footer with options that stays at the bottom of the screen.

But as of right now, if I scroll on the div the footer goes up with the content. I want it to stay at the bottom no matter what.

The main answer I keep seeing is this `(parent).wrapper{position:relative;} )footer).bottom{position:absolute; bottom:0;}`

I've tried it multiple times in different ways but none of them solved this problem and I have been at it all day. Can someone please help me ?

```
 echo "<div class='sub_topics_column'><a href='post.php?postses_id=$post_id'>

     <a href='post.php?postses_id=$post_id'><div class='sub_parent'>

         ...

     </div></a>

    <div class='sub_footer'>

    <div class='comments_footer'>

         <div onClick='javascript:toggle$subtopic_id(event)'
                                        class='newsfeedPostOptions'>

                                        &nbsp;Comments($comments)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

         </div>

         <div class='post_comment' id='toggleComment$subtopic_id'
                                    style='display:none;'>
              <iframe src='comment_frame.php?subtopic_id=$subtopic_id'
                                         id='comment_iframe'
                                        frameborder='0'></iframe>
         </div>

         </div>

         <form method='post' target='frame'>

             <div class='save_footer'>

                 <input style='display: none' type='text' name='current_user'
                                        value=$userLoggedIn />

                 <input style='display: none' type='text' name='post_id'
                                        value=$subtopic_id />

                                       $bookmark_ele

            </div>

           </form>

          <div class='report_footer' onclick='optionsFunction()'>

               <button role='button'>Report</button>

          </div>

          <div class='votes_footer' onClick='javascript:toggle$subtopic_id(event)'>
                                    <iframe id='iframe1' width='49' height='30' scrolling='no'
                                    src='likes.php?post_id=$post_id' ></iframe>
                                </div>

                            </div>

         </div></a><br><br>";
```

styles.css:

```
.sub_topics_column {

margin-top: 1%;
left: 15%;
width: 45%;
height: 475px;
border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: white;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
position: relative;
}

.sub_parent {

top: 2%;
left: 2%;
width: 95%;
height: 100px;
display: flex;
position: relative;
}

.sub_topics_column .sub_footer {

bottom: 0;
left: 0;
height: 33px;
width: 100%;
display: flex;
border: 1px solid #000;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Could you please include your current css so that I can run your code and get an idea of how you want the rest to look.

Comment: @srWebDev just updated it

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question again, I realized you meant something else.
You currently have your footer inside the div with `overflow` enabled. If you place it after that div then it should stay in that position.

So change this

```
     <a href='post.php?postses_id=$post_id'><div class='sub_parent'>

          ...

     </div></a>
```

To this

```
     <div class='sub_comment_wrap'>
          <a href='post.php?postses_id=$post_id'><div class='sub_parent'>

              ...

          </div></a>
     </div>
```

And then for your CSS add and change:

```
.sub_comment_wrap {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sub_topics_column {
    margin-top: 1%;
    left: 15%;
    width: 45%;
    height: 475px;
    border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: white;
}

.sub_parent {
    top: 2%;
    left: 2%;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100px;
}

.sub_topics_column .sub_footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 33px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

And then ofcourse your other changes as needed.

Comment: Just tried that and now the `<div class='sub_footer'>` is not inside the post

Comment: So you will have to create a new wrapper for `<a href='post.php?postses_id=$post_id'><div class='sub_parent'>` and set that one to `overflow-y: auto;`